# keras model.save() isn't saving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a keras NN that I want to train and validate using two sets of data, and then test the ultimate performance of using a third set. In order to avoid having to rerun the training every time I restart my google colab runtime or want to change my test data, I want to save the final state of the model after training in one script and then load it again in another script.

I've looked everywhere and it seems that `model.save("content/drive/My Drive/Directory/ModelName", save_format='tf')` should do the trick, but even though it outputs `INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: content/drive/My Drive/Directory/ModelName/assets` nothing appears in my Google Drive, so I assume it isn't actually saving.

Please can someone help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does writing some sample file to that directory work?

Comment: Yes, later on I do np.savetxt() of a file to the same directory and it saves without problems

Comment: You are missing the starting / in your path, it should be /content/drive/etc, not content/drive,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of saving and retrieving your model's state after **Google Colab** terminated your connection is to use a feature called [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint). This is a `callback` in Keras that would run after each epoch and it will save your model for instance any time there's an improvement. Here's is the steps needed to accomplish what you want:

1. Connect to Google Drive

Use this code in order to connect to Google Drive:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

2. Give access to Google Colab

Then you'll presented with a link that you should go to and after authorizing Google Colab by copying the given code to the text box as shown below:

[image: Google Drive's Authorization Code]

3. Define your `ModelCheckpoint`

This is how you could define your `ModelCheckpoint`'s `callback`:

```py
from keras.callbacks import *

filepath="/content/gdrive/My Drive/MyCNN/epochs:{epoch:03d}-val_acc:{val_acc:.3f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
```

4. Use it as a `callback` in while you're training the model

Then you need to tell your model that after each epoch run this functionality for me to save the model's state.

```py
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=64,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
          callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

5. Load the model after Google Colab terminated

Finally after your session was terminated, you can load your previous model's state by simply running the following code. Don't forget to re-define your model first and only load weights at this stage.

```py
model.load_weights('/content/gdrive/My Drive/MyCNN/epochs:047-val_acc:0.905.hdf5'
```

Hope that this answers your question.

Comment: Extremely clear and didactic explanation! Thank you so much!